# What happens to reputation when I answer my own question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, bounty, accepted-answer

I had a legitimate question that I legitimately needed an answer for, [How to 301 private posts rather than 404?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11427/how-to-301-private-posts-rather-than-404) ,  and I put a bounty of 50 points up to get the answer.

The answers given, at the time I answered it myself, didn't work. I only answered it myself after significant experimentation and discussion on IRC #wordpress.

I wish the other answer worked, as I would have loved to have awarded the points to someone who helped me out, but I think I should get my 50 points back since I did do the work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bounties are not refundable.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

However, good answers tend to get upvoted -- and I for one will almost *always* upvote a self-answered question where the asker put in a lot of effort to find the answer themselves.

I think you might find that you get back what you put in, both in the karmic sense and earthly reputation scores. :)

Comment: I concur. I've seen people like Mike Schinkel subtly blast people for answering their own questions before, but sometimes nobody else has the willingness to go above and beyond to find the answer, you do it yourself and you eventually work it out. Seems a bit taboo sadly to answer your own question, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Dwayne, there's a difference between what Dan did (ask a question, research it, then answer it himself when no one else could) and the asked-and-answered questions Mike and I jump on.  In those cases, someone usually asks a question, then responds with an "oh, I just got it" response less than an hour later. It shows a lack of effort on their part to answer the question and doesn't give the community enough time to respond, either. So not taboo when done correctly.